# XMLHTTP - Read iso-8859-2 content and write UTF-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, vbscript, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I Need read a content from a page that is iso-8859-2 and write in UTF-8 in my code.

Code Example:

```
<%@  language="VBSCRIPT" codepage="65001" %>
<%
    set xmlhttp=Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
    Set re=New RegExp
    re.IgnoreCase=True
    re.Global=True

    xmlhttp.open "get", link, false
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-2"
    xmlhttp.send()
    html=xmlhttp.responsetext

    re.Pattern="<h1>.*?</h1>"
    set aux=re.execute(html)

    text = aux(0)
    response.write text
%>
```

Original Text on Origin:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" >
<h1>Novo público no interior</h1>
```

Today's output on utf-8 page:

```
"Novo pï¿¿o no interior"
```

I Need output the text correctly on UTF-8. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry it's not really an answer, but every time I have to google string encoding I come across this article, read it, sort out my problem, and then generally forget it all a week later.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `.ResponseText` will not decode your `iso-8859-2` see this statement from the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762275(v=vs.85).aspx)

> IXMLHTTP attempts to decode the response into a Unicode string. It assumes the default encoding is UTF-8, but can decode any type of UCS-2 (big or little endian) or UCS-4 encoding as long as the server sends the appropriate Unicode byte-order mark.

Try using `.ResponseBody` instead or failing that use `ADODB.Stream` to take `.ResponseStream` and convert it to `UTF-8` see [ASP: I can´t decode some character from utf-8 to iso-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751893/asp-i-cant-decode-some-character-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1).

Comment: Thanks! Based in your reply, I used the .ResponseBody (But the page came in Binary), so I find a function on Google that convert Binary to String. I just set the Charset in my Page to UTF-8 and "Voilà". Thanks!

Comment: `html = BinaryToString(xmlhttp.responseBody)`

Comment: @MarceloMadnezz Glad it's working for you but you might find the `ADODB.Stream` method to convert the `ISO-8859-2` text to `UTF-8` more robust, rather than converting binary to string (see the link in my answer).

Comment: Just to let you know, I'm using this to read the "News" from my customer Website (That I don't have access to the database) and put their "News" inside my system. I will check the `ADODB.Stream` for sure later.